# Clarification on Spivak's Calculus solutions for Chapter 14, Question 28(e)

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, improper-integrals

I am a little confused with regards to the solutions presented for a particular problem in Spivak's Calculus Chapter 14. The question (sub-part) is as follows:

*Invent a reasonable definition of $\int_{-1}^{1}\left(1-x^2\right)^{-\ \!1/2}dx$, as a sum of two limits, and show that the limits exist. Hint: Why Does $\int_{-1}^{0}\left(1+x\right)^{-\ \!1/2}dx$ exist? How does $\left(1+x\right)^{-\ \!1/2}$ compare with $\left(1-x^2\right)^{-\ \!1/2}$ for $ -1 < x < 0$?*

**Solution:**

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx &= \int_{-1}^{0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to -1^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx + \lim_{\epsilon \to 1^-}\int_{0}^{\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx \\
&= 2 \cdot \lim_{\epsilon \to -1^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx
\end{align*}

Now consider the limit

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to -1^+} \int_{\epsilon}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx
$$

which exists and equals 2 (as shown in an earlier part). For -1 < x < 0 we have

$$
x(1+x) < 0 \\
x < -x^2 \\
1 + x < 1-x^2 \\
\sqrt{1+x} < \sqrt{1-x^2} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2} }
$$

Then, it follows that

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to -1^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
$$

exists.

I do not quite understand how he used the inequality $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ to conclude that the limit of the RHS function exists.

I was under the impression that since the function given by $f(x) = \int_{\epsilon}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ is bounded above by the function $g(x) = \int_{\epsilon}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx$ and $\lim_{\epsilon \to -1^+} \int_{\epsilon}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx$ exists, then it must be the case that $\lim_{\epsilon \to -1^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ is bounded and exists as well. But I brought this up to my lecturer and he remarked that the use of this 'inequality' only works if we know that the limits for both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exists in the first place.

Am I missing out on something? Or is there perhaps a more coherent way of fleshing out this problem? Any advice would be appreciated!